# Syntax error near the keyword 'ON'

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    A.Name, Count(B.ID) AS Policies, Sum(B.Fee) AS Premium
FROM 
    Table1 A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, DATEADD(DAY, (12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,B.CreateDate) % 7 - 6, B.CreateDate) WeekEnding
FROM Table2 B ON A.ID = B.EmpID

WHERE 
    WeekEnding >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    A.Name
ORDER BY 
    Policies DESC, Premium DESC
```

Comment: anything else in the message ? which sql is this ?

Comment: Should there be a ')' after 'WeekEnding FROM Table2'? Not sure.

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

You have **eight** opening brackets here and only **six** closing. SQL needs equal amount of each type of brackets.
Next time just use something like [Notepad ++](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://notepad-plus-plus.org/&ei=91DZUrLIG-uAyAP6xoCgDA&usg=AFQjCNH20Y39KL3umNlz40yN398ALm0wKg&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bGQ) to check you code - it would be much easier to find syntax error with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you?

```
SELECT 
  A.Name, Count(B.ID) AS Policies, Sum(B.Fee) AS Premium
FROM 
    Table1 A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, DATEADD(DAY, (12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,B.CreateDate) % 7 - 6, B.CreateDate) WeekEnding)
FROM Table2 B ON A.ID = B.EmpID

WHERE 
    WeekEnding >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY 
    A.Name
ORDER BY 
    Policies DESC, Premium DESC
```